# retrieve value of input

Tags: javascript, forms, function, dom

I have this:

```
<?php $i=0;?>
<?php foreach($x as $y): ?>
<input type="hidden" id="theid<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $someVariable;?>"/>
<?php $i = $i + 1; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to get the value of each "theid" like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function somefunction(element, optionTitle) {
var num = document.getElementById('theid').value;
...
</script>
```

How can i do that considering the fact that "theid" has the $i added?
Thanks.

Comment: How is `somefunction()` called?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple input fields and you want to do the same action on several, you could use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`:

PHP

```
<input type="hidden" class="theclassname" id="theid<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $someVariable;?>"/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function somefunction(element, optionTitle) {
        var myEles = document.getElementsByClassName('theclassname');
        // loop over myEles and act on each one
        for (var i=0; i < myEles.length; i++) {
            alert("Input with id: " + myEles[i].id + " has value: " + myEles[i].value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can loop through myEles by using myEles.length and myEles.item(i); as myEles should be a nodeList or HTML collection

Comment: @Steve: this isnt working, it is still retrieving value of the first id.

Comment: Well, technically it is retrieving the value of all input fields with the classname of `theclassname`.  It is up to you to figure out which one you want.  But you haven't provided us with how you plan on identifying a particular one.

Comment: I just updated the code in my `for loop` to use alerts.  This will give a better understanding what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery, jQuery selectors support wildcards:

```
$('input[id^=theid]')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for further reading on this topic.

Comment: Not to be an ass, but:  Not everything needs jQuery.  While it might make it look slightly easier, there is a perfectly easy non-jQuery approach to this problem that doesn't require a huge library.

Comment: Take a look at my answer above.  By simply adding a classname, you avoid loading a whole library.

Comment: @Steve: I agree with your statement about including large libraries arbitrarily.  But with that said, using a library such as this can help to speed up development as the main reason I see for using a library like this is for cross-browser compatibility.  As we all know, coding for the plethora of available browsers is not something we want to spend a lot of time on.

Comment: Oh, I am a big fan of jQuery. Of course I would never want to write any of the cross-browser functionality it offers from scratch. But I have a problem when the first answer to a very basic JS question (and one that has no cross-browser issues) becomes: "You should use jQuery."  I write a lot of front-end code and there are many, many situations where standard vanilla JS does the trick. The OP's problem (as stated) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery would be easy like this:

```
$('input[id^="theid"]').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).val()); //value of each theid
});
```

Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ucahik/2/edit).